# Clarify Ubuntu One sync behavior

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I'm seeking clarification of Ubuntu One behavior with regard to syncing folders. Here's what I'm experiencing:

1. ~/Ubuntu One syncs to the web site and to all machines that share the U1 account.
2. Other synchronized folders (i.e. not ~/Ubuntu One) sync to the web site, but not to other machines that share the U1 account.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional. You have to enable those folders to be synced on other computers. You can do that in the Ubuntu One control panel, under Cloud folders. You may wish to have some folders synced on all your personal computers and others on your office computers, for instance.